# Abnormal Taste of Potato

Tags: word-request

What is the word for unpleasantly sweet taste of potato? (We often have such potatoes in India. They taste very bad, with a tinge of sweetness.)

Comment: Can you describe the bad taste better? Just "sweetness" doesn't really help, since that could describe a sweet potato.

Comment: Maybe it's *cloying*, maybe it's *mawkish*, I'm not sure. But it sounds like something *sickly sweet*.

Comment: Is this potato raw, baked or boiled? Seasoned, or not? Fresh, or old? Rotten? (I hope not.)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock It's old and boiled. And it's not rotten.

Comment: an **acrid** taste is good for describing something broadly as pungent and anyway from mildly odd to foul.  *The sweet but acrid taste of the potato made her stomach turn...*

Comment: Note that a [sweet potato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_potato) is not a potato.  It's a different plant entirely.  So to avoid confusion, we shouldn't use the phrase "sweet potato" to refer to a potato that's sweet.

Comment: This might actually be better suited to the cooking SE... they might better understand what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

For anything that tastes bad I would use the word [**foul**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foul); to add a tinge of sweetness to that it would probably be phrased **foul, sugary taste**.

A more moderate version of this would be the phrase you used: **unpleasantly sweet**

As you are looking for a single word, there is one: [**sweetish**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweetish) which can mean somewhat sweet and unpleasantly sweet. [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sweetish) actually gives this example of usage:

> *It has a sweetish taste, much like that of a frost-bitten potato, and I found it better boiled than roasted.*

(originally form Walden & on the Duty of Civil Disobedience by Thoreau, Henry David).

Comment: You might use "sweetish"... but I've never heard the word before, so I don't think it'd be widely comprehended to mean a slightly foul taste and it certainly has no direct relation to potatoes.